# Es posible agregar ceros a la derecha

Tags: python

ocurre que tengo un número entero por ejemplo 15, cuando lo paso a float Python lo imprime como 15.0, es posible agregarle un cero a la derecha y que me imprima "15.00"

Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿La idea es imprimirlo con print(numero) directamente? ¿O está dentro de alguna estructura o contenedor (lista, DataFrame, etc) y se imprime al imprimir este?

Comment: no solo para imprimirlo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes agregarle un cero a la derecha al objeto `float` como tal, pero si solo quieres que se imprima mostrando dos decimales rellenando con ceros si es necesario, basta con usar formato de cadenas:

```
n = 15.0
print(f'{n:.2f}')
```

si usas Python < 3.6 usa `str.format` en lugar de literales de cadena formateados:

```
n = 15.0
print('{:.2f}'.format(n))
```

Si vas a realizar esta operación repetidamente puede resultarte más cómodo usar una función, algo como:

```
def printf(n, decimals=2):
    print(f"{n:.{decimals}f}")
```

> ```
> >>> printf(4.2)
> 4.20
> >>> printf(15.0)
> 15.00
> >>> printf(15.0, 4)
> 15.0000
> ```

Comment: Muchas gracias y si quiero usar el formato: file.write() como hago, veo que no lo escribe

Comment: A write le puedes pasar la cadena iguaal que haces a print: `file.write(f'{n:.2f}')`. ¿O te refieres usando la función?

Comment: Si van a votar negativamente, pongan sus razones, uno escribe una pregunta por que necesita ayuda no?